# CSS animation out after removal of class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a slider that has a fade-in and fade-out transition. It basically cycles and switches my `<li></li>` elements and add `.current` class to the active slide. look something like this  `<li class="current"></li>`.

**What do you think is the solution on my code?** http://jsbin.com/evayaw/

I just added a button to add a class (`.active`) on the slides to mimic my slider behavior. The object inside each slide animates upon adding `.active` class on the parent `<li>` container. It should also transistion out after removing the `.active` class. The transitions would normally do the opposite property, Eg. from `opacity: 1;` it will go to `opacity 0;` or from `left: 100;` to `left: 0;`.

**Similar:** http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/ - this uses different approach with my existing slider, so i can't use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/evayaw/35

If you click 2 and then 3 and then 2, is that what you want? Part of the problem was when you removed .active it would no longer have `z-index:9999;`. I added a `.unActive` (which also has `z-index:9998;`, and also added a `.delay'.

Also, using href tags you kept going to top of page to I removed them. (I guess I could have had them stop default behavior, but I put `a` properties into `li`, and also gave `li` a mouse pointer attribute. I also have your clicks use nth_of_type(), but you can remove that, just helped me make sure your buttons weren't the problem.

**EDIT:** Also when you want a animation to 'reverse' instead of `.object_#` you put `.unActive .object_#`